# How to Capitalize first letter of each word in ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box for listing locations. The list includes id and value.

My script goes like this

```
    <script>
    $scope.fillLocationList = function (item) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: {                            
                        'country': item
                    }
                }).then(function (result) {
                    $scope.LocatorList = result.data;                                                        
                });
            };
    $scope.fillLocationList($scope.formData.country);
    </script>
<select name="location" id="location" class="selectcontact" ng-model="formData.locations" ng-options="item.key_value for item in LocatorList track by item.key_id"></select>
```

I need to display place name as "Dubai Internet City".

How can I make the list capitalize for each word in angularjs?

Comment: Inside .then() function execute loop and make word capitalize using function.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039226/angularjs-format-text-return-from-json-to-title-case) question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter **[`uppercase`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase)**

```
ng-options="item.key_value as (item.key_value | uppercase) for item in LocatorList track by item.key_id"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I need to capitalize only the first letter not the whole word.

Comment: I made custom filter for capitalize.

Comment: why did you remove

Comment: your filter was to capitalize the whole word.

Comment: why what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

included custom filter

```
$scope.filter('capitalize', function() {
        return function(input) {
            return (!!input) ? input.split(' ').map(function(wrd){return wrd.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + wrd.substr(1).toLowerCase();}).join(' ') : '';
        }
    });

ng-options="item.key_value as (item.key_value | capitalize) for item in LocatorList track by item.key_id"
```